# Transfer Layerswp website to another Server?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created my website in demo folder using wordpress. I have used "Layers WordPress site builder". The problem is when I transfer all data and database to new server, pages show no data.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a big problem with LayersWP it seems. I don't know for sure what the cause is but I've noticed that the database after the import is a different size to the database exported

Not the perfect solution to the problem... but this was a good work around for me:

This plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-settings-importexport/

Let's you import and export widgets. I'd advise leaving the working site in tact and only importing into a new database.